# preview iTunes/Last.fm tracks from withing app

Tags: iphone, itunes, xamarin.ios, last.fm

Is it possible to allow users to preview music from either Last.fm or iTunes from within my app?

Are apple OK with apps streaming preview clips of music in apps?

This is a monotouch app.

w://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using the Apple iTunes Search API.

Comment: http://iwayneo.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-restsharp-to-access-itunes-search.html

explains how i did it